Is CRS specified in XML file with GPX data?
I am using a Python script that reads the SRID (Spatial Reference Identifier) in various file formats. If the SRID is found, the file is packed, stored and can then be imported (QGIS etc.). Unfortunately, it does not work in the case of GPX.
I therefore consulted Google and, as far as I understood correctly, GPX does not need an EPSG code or CRS in XML - as a GPX file is always saved in WGS84 format.
So there is no attribute for the coordinate system or SRID in the XML file, is that correct?
At first, I thought I could solve the problem by opening the original GPX file in QGIS, creating a new CRS and then exporting it. However, the file was already correctly in WGS84 (and in the XML, checked with Notepad, there is no entry for a CRS anywhere).

GPX is always using WGS84 lat/lon coordinates. Otherwise it is invalid. QGIS  knows that and thus should have no trouble in reading or writing. What is exactly the issue that you have?

My problem is that the Python script cannot find an SRID and therefore aborts. Formats such as SHP, TIF etc. run through with the script, but GPX does not. Apparently this is because GPX necessarily uses WGS84.
With my question I actually wanted to clarify whether I have understood correctly that WGS84 is always present (must be present) and whether there is a possibility to define the SRID in the GPX file.
But the answer helps me, because at least it is now clear that WGS84 is a requirement for a GPX file.
This means that the Python script has to be modified.

How is your python script looking for an SRID in a GPX file? Or in any other file? Did you expect some tag to define the SRID? GPX files should be natively readable in QGIS anyway so I don't know why you need to "pack and store" it for import to QGIS...

The script was not written by me - but this is exactly how it should work -> search/find SRID and then various steps are run through. Exactly, a tag is expected but not found in the case of the GPX. But my question is answered so far (the script is therefore unsuitable for this file format).

The script could made to recognize the GPX format, maybe be checking if the XML contains xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1. The CRS is defined there <xsd:documentation> GPX schema version 1.1 - For more information on GPX and this schema, visit http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp GPX uses the following conventions: all coordinates are relative to the WGS84 datum. All measurements are in metric units. </xsd:documentation> Another similar "always WGS84" format is KML.

The CRS of GPX files is specified in the XML file but not directly. All valid GPX files have a pointer to the GPX schema
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"

The xsd schema defines the coordinate system

GPX uses the following conventions: all coordinates are relative to
the WGS84 datum. All measurements are in metric units.

...
<xsd:attribute name="lat" type="latitudeType" use="required">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation> The latitude of the point. This is always in decimal degrees, and always in WGS84 datum. </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:attribute>
<xsd:attribute name="lon" type="longitudeType" use="required">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation> The longitude of the point. This is always in decimal degrees, and always in WGS84 datum. </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:attribute>

